# Intent Redirection Vulnerability Android Content Provider

Tags: android-security

There is a content provider in the application that I send a sticker to the whats up application.

```
    <provider
        android:name=".whatsappsticker.StickerContentProvider"
        android:authorities="${stickerContentProviderAuthority}"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ" />
```

In the report from Google, it says that I should edit it as exported = false, but it is impossible for me to send stickers this way.

How can I solve this problem without making exported = false?

Best wishes

Comment: Can you include the text from the rejection letter?

Comment: Your app contains an Intent Redirection vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details. Just this with this link https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555

Comment: I also removed this content provider in my app however it came back with the same issue. I removed it because there is only one component exported = true in my app, thats why I removed it. I could not found any useful information about my case in google's review message. Is there anywhere where I can find a detail message in google play console ?